# find nth value in fib sequence javascript using previously declared variables

Tags: javascript, variables, fibonacci

I'm trying to find the nth value of the fib sequence in javascript, but I got stuck with another problem prior to that and I'm trying to understand why.

```
function nthFib(n) {
  var fib = [0, 1];
  var l = fib[fib.length-1];
  var s = fib[fib.length-2];  

  while(fib.length < n) {
    fib.push(fib[fib.length-1] + fib[fib.length-2]);
  }

  console.log(fib); 

}

nthFib(5);
```

Right now when I console log I'm getting what I want which is the array building up: [0, 1, 1, 2, 3]

BUT if I do this in the while loop instead to have cleaner code:

```
while(fib.length < n) {
  fib.push(s + l);
}
```

I guess my while loop doesn't have access to those variables and in turn I get this result: [0, 1, 1, 1, 1]

WHY?

Comment: If you're storing the whole sequence history it may consume a lot of memory for large `n`

Answer (score 2):

I think this is a much better function as it uses a linear iterative process with proper tail recursion

```
function fib(n) {
  function iter(xs, i, a, b) {
    if (i === 0) return xs;
    return iter(xs.concat(b), i-1, b, a+b);
  }
  return iter([0], n, 0, 1);
}
```

Examples

```
fib(0);
//=> [ 0 ]
fib(1);
//=> [ 0, 1 ]
fib(2);
//=> [ 0, 1, 1 ]
fib(3);
//=> [ 0, 1, 1, 2 ]
fib(4);
//=> [ 0, 1, 1, 2, 3 ]
fib(5);
//=> [ 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5 ]
fib(6);
//=> [ 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8 ]
fib(10);
//=> [ 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55 ]
```

Explanation

The `iter` function takes 4 state variables

- `xs` - the fib series, initalized with `[ 0 ]`
- `i` - the decrementing iterator used to terminate the recursion, initialized with `n`
- `a` - the first fib number, initialized with `0`
- `b` - the second fib number, initialized with `1`

The way this works is, once `i` has reached `0`, `xs` will be returned.

Let's see how `fib(5)` is computed

```
//   xs             i  a  b
// -----------------------------
iter([0],           5, 0, 1);
iter([0,1],         4, 1, 1);
iter([0,1,1],       3, 1, 2);
iter([0,1,1,2],     2, 2, 3);
iter([0,1,1,2,3],   1, 3, 5);
iter([0,1,1,2,3,5], 0, 5, 8);
// -----------------------------
//=> [0,1,1,2,3,5]
```

---

ES6

Using a U-combinator with ES6, you can get a pretty slimmed down version of the same function

```
// ES6
let fib = n => (
  f => f(f, [0], n, 0, 1)
)(
  (f, xs, i, a, b) => i === 0 ? xs : f(f, xs.concat(b), i-1, b, a+b)
);

fib(10);
//=> [ 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55 ]
```

Cool !

Comment: `fib()` called without parameter appear to return `RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`

Comment: @guest271314 that's correct. `fib` requires a number input.

Answer (score 1):

You have to modify `s, l` inside the while loop. Take a look at this code.

```
function nthFib(n) {
  var fib = [0, 1];


  while(fib.length < n) {

      var l = fib[fib.length-1];
      var s = fib[fib.length-2];  
      fib.push(s + l);

  }

  console.log(fib); 

}

nthFib(5);
```

Comment: ok but why? Is it because as long as the condition in the while loop holds true it doesn't have access to those previous variables? If that's the case how does it still know what fib is?

Comment: it is because, each time you try find the fib value, you need the last two fib values you found. When the while loop runs, it only modifies the code which has in its own block. It does not jump back and edit the previous code. So you must have the l, s inside the while loops block itself. clear?

Comment: Yes! So it only has access to fib, not to l & s, right?

Comment: It can access l & s. But you have to actually access it and modify it. It won't automatically modify the values. clear?